# Преобразование строки в выражение

Tags: php

Как преобразовать строку в выражение?

```
$a = "$c.$b"; // string
$c = "мама";
$b = "папа";

// функция, преобразующая строку в выражение, либо регулярное выражение

echo $a; // выводим "мамапапа";
```

Comment: вы сначала мануал почитайте, пожалуйста. http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Здесь товарищу не нужны строковые операторы - ему нужно именно "выполнить выражение из строки". Пример - да, странный, но он нужен лишь для того, чтобы показать, чего ему нужно.

Comment: Вам трудно написать так: `$c.".".$b` в место `"$c.$b"`? если я правильно понял вопрос.

Comment: @ВикторВасильев В целом зачем это и чего хотите достичь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через **[переменные переменных](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php)**. Надо будет только в строке `$a` убрать у переменных доллары

```
$a = 'c.b'; 
$c = "мама";
$b = "папа";

$temp = explode('.', $a);

foreach ($temp as $item) {
    echo $$item;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Автор, если вы хотите получить в ответ строку **мамапапа**, то достаточно провести [конкатенацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php) строк

```
$c = "мама";
$b = "папа";
$a = $c . $b;

echo $a; // выводим "мамапапа";
```

или так

```
$c = "мама";
$b = "папа";
$a = "$c$b";

echo $a; // выводим "мамапапа";
```

Если же вы действительно хотите вычислить выражение из строки, то строку следует составить в соответствии с синтаксисом php:

```
$a = '$a = $c . $b;'; // string
$c = "мама";
$b = "папа";

// выполняем строку как код php
eval($a);

echo $a; // выводим "мамапапа";
```

Но использование функции `eval()` не рекомендуется из-за возможных проблем с безопасностью выполнения кода.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo eval($a);
```

Такой вариант не пойдёт?

[ссылка](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php)

Comment: И выведет у вас строку: `сын Петя`

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in .... : eval()'d code on line 1`